# Error while creating procedure in db2

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2

I got error while creating procedure in db2.

Error is - Expected tokens may include: psm_semicolon.. SQLCODE=-104

Help Me....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_new()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE TEMP(METADATA_KEY varchar(40),NEW_METADATA_KEY varchar(40));
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In whatever tool you're using, change the statement terminator to something other than semicolon and put that terminator at the end of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

For example, if using the command line processor, save this to a file (note the "@" symbol at the end:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_new()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
 CREATE TABLE TEMP(METADATA_KEY varchar(40),NEW_METADATA_KEY varchar(40));
END@
```

then execute the file: `db2 -td@ -f myproc.sql`

The reason for doing this is that semicolons are always used as terminators *within* the procedure code, so you must use something else to terminate the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.